# CMUSphinx cmuclmtk file not found error

Tags: cmusphinx

Im trying to run this line in cmd:

```
% idngram2lm -vocab_type 0 -idngram weather.idngram -vocab \
 weather.vocab -arpa weather.arpa
```

But im getting the that idngram file that I specified doesn't exists, which it does.
Help?

Comment: Please post the entire run, along with error message, and with `pwd` result from before calling the tool; also - what is your operating system? cmd implies Windows, but please confirm.

Comment: Yes I am on windows.
Here is the error plus dir before calling the tool:
[link](http://pastebin.com/ntxU161W)

Comment: I think that the tool is having a problem with parsing large files. Try to use the tool on a small file.

Comment: But it's only one file, it was created by a tool and it can't be parted in the tool.

Comment: Sorry; the file is there and the error message hints us that there is a problem with opening the file. In that case, the application is most likely buggy and doesn't use fopen64 which allows for opening large files. Try to compile the tool yourself on a modern linux, it may work better.

Comment: How am I suppose to compile the tool on linux? I am running Windows OS but I do have linux installed on a VM, but never the less how am I suppose to compile to tool, it's not my own its from here: [link](http://bit.ly/18wfeju)

Comment: You have to find it in the repository: http://sourceforge.net/projects/cmusphinx/files/

Comment: ok, i've downloaded the src, I can't see anything that can help me though, mind telling me again what I need to do?

Comment: You have to find and compile the tool that you are using on windows, and then use it on linux

Comment: I'm sorry but it seems my Linux VM isn't working, isn't there another way to do this?